# EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC11: Changed php files are not refreshed immediately

Tags: php, opcache

I have replaced my Zend Server CE with an EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC11 install, running PHP 5.5.3. When I make changes in a php file, the changes often show only after waiting about a minute followed by a browser refresh. This is quite annoying in a development environment.

Can this be changed in the php.ini or is there some other way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out. I fixed the problem by changing `opcache.revalidate_freq` from `60` (nonsensical default for development) to `2` in the php.ini.

Comment: Set `opcache.revalidate_freq=0` for development.  It makes sense always to revalidate when developing.  The runtime impact of stat'ing files will be minimal in this use case, but this will totally avoid any of these edge effects